# h1 doesn't slide into page smoothly

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm animating two headers to slide into the page from the opposite sides however the second header (job role) doesn't slide in smoothly (it slides in with some of the words on another line and slowly becomes one line). Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahni1/pen/dyozymq) which will convey my issue more clearly. How can I fix this?

```css
.skewedBox {
    background: #edff57;
    padding: 115px 0;
    transform: skew(20, 0, 0, 40deg) translateY(-120px);
}
.container {
    padding: 150px 200px;
    transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
    font-family: arial;
} 
.name {
    margin-top: 90px;
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    font-size: 3em;
}
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% {margin-left: -1600px;}
    100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
.role {
    color: black;
    animation-name: slideInRight;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    font-size: 3em;
}
@keyframes slideInRight {
    0% {margin-left: 1600px;}
    100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <section class="skewedBox">
        <div className="container">
            <h1 class="name">Hi, I'm ...</h1>
            <h1 class="role">A {This is a job role}. </h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `white-space: nowrap;` for your content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```css
.skewedBox {
  background: #edff57;
  /*padding: 115px 0;*/
  transform: skew(20, 0, 0, 40deg) translateY(-120px);
}
.container {
  padding: 150px 200px;
    transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
  font-family: arial;
}

.name {
    margin-top: 90px;
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  font-size: 3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {margin-left: -1600px;}
  100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}

.role {
  color: black;
  animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  font-size: 3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {margin-left: 1600px;}
  100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <section class="skewedBox">
    <div className="container">
<h1 class="name">Hi, I'm {My Long name here}</h1>
<h1 class="role">A {This is a job role}. </h1>
</div>
</section>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add in CSS to `.skewedBox`: `overflow: hidden;`